# add files to xcodeproj from command line

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction, xcodebuild

I need add header and library into project file from command line. (need change project file)

I've looked **project.pbxproj** it looks not friendly :)

Is exist way to add files to xcodeproj correctly ?
Of course it will be running only in MACOS.

Thanks,

Comment: MAXOS, for maximum OS performance. ;-)

Comment: I've found [this soulution](http://bluezbox.com/blog/15/managing-xcode-projects-from-command-line). Is really simplest way ?

Comment: So far, Yes. It's really troublesome when you have to support targets..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this ruby file](http://cl.ly/code/0C2h3M2r1z2z) should be useful in setting up a scriptable solution
i've used it to edit build phases for a project from an automated script based on configuration

Comment: Could you fix the link or just embed the entire script in the answer?